# Inkscape files move when opened in multiple programs

Tags: inkscape

When I open an SVG file in Chrome, Internet Explorer, GIMP etc, one object moves from where I put it in Inkscape. How can I prevent this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you haven't converted the text to outlines.  If you leave text as editable text, nearly every application will render that text ever so slightly differently. Also if the font you used isn't available on another computer, those viewing it won't see the same font.

In your example SVGs, the "Student Voice" text I see is an entirely different font from the one shown in your google drive thumbnails. I also noticed the large letter V, which is still editable text, renders slightly differently across different applications.

For consistency across all devices and applications, convert all text to outlines when outputting the final SVG for the web. Also better to use the "Plain SVG" file type when saving the final files for use on the web.